# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ailson.mavenproj.factory.JPAUtil

Tags: java

Estou tendo fazer uma inserção simples no banco de dados em java web usando o JPA, hibernate e maven. O problema é que está aparecendo erro `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, e não consigo ver onde está o erro. Deem uma olhada no Stack Trace abaixo:

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ailson.mavenproj.factory.JPAUtil
>     at com.ailson.mavenproj.DAO.PessoaDAO.persistir(PessoaDAO.java:20)
>     at com.ailson.mavenproj.controller.PessoaBean.persistir(PessoaBean.java:33)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:311)
>     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:415)
>     at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
>     at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>     at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
>     at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> ```

Eis o meu código:

```java
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.ailson.mavenproj.factory;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 *
 * @author Programmer
 */
public class JPAUtil {

    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    static {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Teste");
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static void close() {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

```java
public class PessoaDAO {

    public void persistir(String nome) {

        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
        p.setNome(nome);
        em.persist(p);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        JPAUtil.close();

    }
}
```

```java
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.ailson.mavenproj.controller;

import com.ailson.mavenproj.DAO.PessoaDAO;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author Programmer
 */
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PessoaBean {

    private String nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void persistir() {

        PessoaDAO d = new PessoaDAO();
        d.persistir(this.nome);

    }

}
```

> ```
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     at com.ailson.mavenproj.DAO.PessoaDAO.persistir(PessoaDAO.java:20)
>     at com.ailson.mavenproj.controller.PessoaBean.persistir(PessoaBean.java:33)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:311)
>     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:415)
>     at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
>     at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>     at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
>     at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Teste] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:953)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:883)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>     at com.ailson.mavenproj.factory.JPAUtil.<clinit>(JPAUtil.java:21)
>     ... 65 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:34)
>     at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDefaultDdlTransactionIsolator(Helper.java:145)
>     at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.HibernateSchemaManagementTool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(HibernateSchemaManagementTool.java:180)
>     at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:90)
>     at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
>     at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:476)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:422)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:880)
>     ... 69 more
> ```

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Teste" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQL-DS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.ailson.mavenproj.model.Pessoa</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mavendb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="lala"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Posta o stacktrace como texto e o código completo (inclusive a instrução `package`) da classe `JPAUtil`por favor

Comment: ja coloquei em cima  da uma olhada

Comment: Coloca o código da classe `JPAUtil` também por favor

Comment: ja coloquei em cima

Comment: Seu erro parece estar no `factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Teste");`, mas o erro gerado acaba sendo ocultado pelo `NoClassDefFoundError`. Faça o seguinte, substitua essa linha por `try { factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Teste"); } catch (RuntimeException | Error e) { e.printStackTrace(); throw e; }` e diga o que aparece.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Cara ja esta da uma olha ali

Comment: @AilsonDelgado Ah, isso mostra que há um problema nas transações. O que há no seu `persistence.xml`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa ja coloquei o persistence.xml da uma olha

Answer (score 0):

Retire essa linha do seu `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQL-DS</jta-data-source>
```

Você está gerenciando a criação do `EntityManager` ao criar você mesmo o `EntityManagerFactory`. No entanto o `<jta-data-source>` é usado nos casos onde o container de aplicação é que gerencia o `EntityManager`.

Mais informações [nessa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7181673/540552).

Comment: E o seguinte, o container que estou utilizando e o wildfly e eu fiz as configuracoes do data-source no standalone do wildfly e utilizei no arquivo persistence.xml para poder gerar a tabelas no banco de dados ao rodar o container, se eu remover o <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQL-DS</jta-data-source> sera que vai dar problema?